# Parse data between %%

Tags: php, parsing, zend-framework

could you please tell me if the string between %% can be parsed so that instead of displaying e.g. %offerroomlistBox% , I can render another view that will display the data I need.

[image: view]

I get the data from the database , their var_dump looks like this

[image: var_dump of data]

The only thing I use is 'description'

I display the data on the ckeditor with the simplest

```
<textarea >
echo $this->templatesList[0]['description']
</textarea >
```

templatesList is a list taken from database in such way

```
    $TemplatesModel = new TemplatesModel();
    $this->view->templatesList = $TemplatesModel->getAll(['where'=>["kind='offers_email'"]]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
echo str_replace('%','',$this->templatesList[0]['description']);
```

to learn about str_replace, please visit here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Its good but it wont let me to parse other "% % " values , only one.Is it possible to parse whole array and check all posibilites?

Comment: Got it  , str_replace works with arrays.